# Performance difference between reassigning variable and redefining

Tags: javascript, variables

Which style is better practice for performance in Javascript?

**Style1**

```
var x = ''
for(var i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i ++){
    x = ....
    //do something with x
 }
```

**Style2**

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i ++){
    var x = ....
    //do something with x
 }
```

Comment: I'd stick with the 2nd example purely for semantic reasons. That said though it's more common to define all your required variables at the top of the current scope (e.g. function).

Comment: http://jsperf.com/omgggggfdfsdfsdfsdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**JavaScript doesn't have block scope** like some other languages, only function scope. This means that in practice the JS engine interprets the first version of your code as:

```
var i, x = '';    
for(i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i ++){
    x = ....
    //do something with x
}
```

And the second version exactly the same except without assigning a default `''` value to `x`:

```
var i, x;    
for(i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i ++){
    x = ....
    //do something with x
}
```

So in my opinion "Style 1" is bad practice because you assign a value that is never used. But I think "Style 2" is worse because it implies block scope that doesn't exist.

As for which performs better, without testing it I'd expect both to be pretty much the same with any modern JS engine.

Comment: What about defining the variable within the for loop though as opposed to before the loop itself?

Comment: What I'm saying is that even when you think you're declaring a variable inside a for loop you aren't really because JS doesn't have block scope. The JS engine uses a mechanism known as "hoisting" to basically pretend that your `var` statements were at the top of the containing scope, though assignments are _not_ hoisted. The structure of code in my answer shows how the JS engine treats the code from your question. The scope of your `x` and `i` variables are not restricted just to that for loop even though your "style 2" makes it look like they would be.

Answer (score 0):

I would always recommend using local variables as much as possible due to the scope chain performance tuning available in javascript.
Read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jscript/archive/2007/07/26/scope-chain-of-jscript-functions.aspx for more information.

Comment: To answer your particular situation it depends on what exactly your block of code wishes to do using the globally assigned variables. If its referenced multiple times then its much better to use the second one.